# The same graph is repeated in my view and upon page refresh, the graph changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is my loop in the Controller. I am trying to create and display a chart using Angular JS but I am unable to do so. The same graph is repeated in my view and upon page refresh, the graph changes. I want the response "Options" and "Votes" from the JSON. What mistake am I making?

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.response.options.length;i++) {
      labels.push(response.response.options[i].options);
                  data.push(response.response.options[i].votes);
                  $scope.labels = labels;
                  $scope.data = [
                      data        
                  ];
```

This is my JSON. I have multiple calls and thus multiple JSONs like this are called from the API.

```
{
  "response": {
    "poll": {
      "id": "17",
      "story_id": "28346",
      "user_id": "32425",
      "question": "Who's your favorite actor?",
      "status": "1",
      "docs": "1473121969"
    },
    "options": [
      {
        "id": "59",
        "options": "1. Hamza Ali Abbasi",
        "image_url": "31xjr2a6f838gwqkw68p.png",
        "doc": "1473121970",
        "votes": "3"
      },
      {
        "id": "60",
        "options": "2. Emmad Irfani",
        "image_url": "w9yhbtlr39pzn9d9bijf.png",
        "doc": "1473121970"
      },
      {
        "id": "61",
        "options": "3. Shahbaz Shigri",
        "image_url": "hxnbem90wtlo7eb8tuew.png",
        "doc": "1473122087"
      },
      {
        "id": "62",
        "options": "4. Fawad Khan",
        "image_url": "f9q6ud83bjt8ateazzzs.png",
        "doc": "1473122111"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you are getting at, with why it isn't working, and that may be your "data" array. Here is a jsfiddle that has it working and displaying the info you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/jwb9acqL/

If you look at the console output of the object in your original code, the output was:

```
[labels: Array[4], data: Array[1]]
```

Where the "votes" in data were for some reason put in another subarray:

```
$scope.data = [
                  data        
              ];
```

I removed that extra array. See if that helps. If not, I would say you need to post the graph code.